# Find specific example for where the case works (topic: isomorphism and normal subgroups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Consider groups $G_i, K_i, F_i$ such that $K_i \triangleleft G_i$ and $G_i / K_i\cong F_i$ , for $i = 1, 2$. In each case, find an example with the given properties or prove that no such example exists. If you give an example, justify why $K_i \triangleleft G_i$ and $G_i / K_i\cong  F_i$ and the various (non)isomorphisms.

a) $G_1 \ncong  G_2$ and $K_1 \cong  K_2$ and $F_1\cong  F_2.$

---

I know that if we set $G_1 = G_2$ and $K_1 = K_2$ and $F_1 = F_2$, then they're all false. But, I need to find a specific example where it's possible, or if it is impossible.
I'm not sure which ones are impossible, because I can't seem to come up with any examples.

---

$\triangleleft$ is for normal subgroup, and $\cong$ is for isomorphic here.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun should I remove one of the parts of a, b, c then?

Comment: Remove two of a, b, and c.

Comment: Ask them in a different post.

Comment: Hint: why not try some (very) small examples? Take two non-isomorphic groups of the same order for $G_i$, and see if you can find suitable subgroups $K_i$.

Comment: I can't find it right now, but there is  already a post that discusses all cases: you can have $G_1\cong G_2$, $K_1\cong K_2$, and $(G_1/K_1)\not\cong (G_2/K_2)$. You can have $G_1\cong G_2$, $(G_1/K_1)\cong (G_2/K_2)$, and $K_1\not\cong K_2$. And you can have $K_1\cong K_2$, $(G_1/K_1)\cong (G_2/K_2)$, and $G_1\not\cong G_2$. With finite groups and small examples. Even abelian groups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i've been looking for a post discussing this, but I couldn't find one. If you stumble across that post again, i'd really appreciate the link for it